# How to compare two numbers in a line which are not same in length and print them

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-matching

I have a file from which I have to extract lines containing "TCP 0.0.0.0" and ongoing text, then compare the two numbers next to it and print line only if their lengths are not equal.

I have below code which extracts only lines containing "TCP 0.0.0.0" and ongoing text, but I need to filter again by comparing the two numbers next to it and print if length are not equal:

```
import re

f = open("log.txt", "r")
counter = 0
print("="*20)
for line in f:
  match = re.search("(TCP 0\.0\.0\.0) (.*) (ongoing)", line)
  if match:
    counter += 1
    print("-"*10)

    # If you want to print the whole line
    print("Count {}:[F] {}".format(counter, line.rstrip()))

    # if you want to print just the matched section
    # print("Count {}:[M] {}".format(counter, match.groups()   [1].rstrip()))

print("="*20)
print("Total Found: {}".format(counter))
f.close()
```

log.txt:

```
Dash#07-06-2019 18:04:32 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" tetet 534049 533799 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78

Do#07-06-2019 18:04:32 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 80 15 Regular "policy2" ongoing 77010 76760 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CFADC78

07-06-2019 18:04:37 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" ongoing 53408 533837 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78

 07-06-2019 18:04:37 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 80 15 Regular "policy2" ongoing 770124 76762 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CFADC78

 D#07-06-2019 18:04:42 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" ongoing 535 533822 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78
```

Need to print below three lines from file. As it contains "TCP 0.0.0.0" and ongoing text also "53408,533837" numbers length is not same (in front of ongoing text):

```
  07-06-2019 18:04:37 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first  packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" ongoing 53408 533837 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78

 07-06-2019 18:04:37 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 80 15 Regular "policy2" ongoing 770124 76762 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CFADC78

 D#07-06-2019 18:04:42 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" ongoing 535 533822 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78
```

Comment: `awk` is far better suited to this.

Comment: Am newbie to python, Can you plz help

Comment: you can use `split('ongoing')[1]` to get all text after `ongoing` and then you can `split(' ')[0:2]` to get both numbers after `ongoing`

Comment: @AlfredE.Noobman That is both wrong and unhelpful.

Comment: @John You just need to extend the regexp so that it captures the ongoing numbers as well: `re.search(r"TCP 0\.0\.0\.0 (.+?) ongoing (\d+) (\d+)", line)`. Now `match.groups()` will return a tuple containing all the elements you are interested in.

Comment: ekhumoror - Not wrong. This can be achieved in a single line using `awk` and it will be much more efficient. Perhaps I should have provided an example to be more helpful. Matching is trivial - `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="ongoing" && $(i+1)!=$(i+2)) print $(i+1) " is not equal to " $(i+2)}' file`  - Job done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split('ongoing ')[1]` to get all text after `"ongoing"` and then you can `split(' ')[0:2]` to get both numbers after `"ongoing"`

```
import re

data = '''Dash#07-06-2019 18:04:32 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" tetet 534049 533799 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78
Do#07-06-2019 18:04:32 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 80 15 Regular "policy2" ongoing 77010 76760 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CFADC78
07-06-2019 18:04:37 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" ongoing 53408 533837 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78
07-06-2019 18:04:37 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 80 15 Regular "policy2" ongoing 770124 76762 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CFADC78
D#07-06-2019 18:04:42 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" ongoing 535 533822 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78
'''

f = data.split('\n')

for line in f:
    match = re.search("(TCP 0\.0\.0\.0) (.*) (ongoing)", line)
    if match:
        second_part = line.split(' ongoing ')[1]
        numbers = second_part.split(' ')[:2]

        number1 = numbers[0]
        number2 = numbers[1]

        print(number1, 'len:', len(number1))
        print(number2, 'len:', len(number2))

        if len(number1) != len(number2):
            print('different lengths')

        print('---')
```

Result:

```
77010 len: 5
76760 len: 5
---
53408 len: 5
533837 len: 6
different lengths
---
770124 len: 6
76762 len: 5
different lengths
---
535 len: 3
533822 len: 6
different lengths
```

---

**EDIT:** Or you can create more complex regex which will get numbers

```
re.search("TCP 0\.0\.0\.0 (.*) ongoing (\d+) (\d+)", line)
```

Code:

```
import re

data = '''Dash#07-06-2019 18:04:32 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" tetet 534049 533799 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78
Do#07-06-2019 18:04:32 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 80 15 Regular "policy2" ongoing 77010 76760 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CFADC78
07-06-2019 18:04:37 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" ongoing 53408 533837 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78
07-06-2019 18:04:37 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 80 15 Regular "policy2" ongoing 770124 76762 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-002A-00005CFADC78
D#07-06-2019 18:04:42 WARNING 240 Anomalies "TCP handshake violation, first packet not syn" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 0.0.0.0 0 15 Regular "policy1" ongoing 535 533822 0 0 N/A low drop FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-0029-00005CFADC78
'''

f = data.split('\n')

for line in f:
    match = re.search("TCP 0\.0\.0\.0 (.*) ongoing (\d+) (\d+)", line)
    if match:
        number1 = match.group(2)
        number2 = match.group(3)

        print(number1, 'len:', len(number1))
        print(number2, 'len:', len(number2))

        if len(number1) != len(number2):
            print('different lengths')

        print('---')
```

Comment: I need to get data from file not from constant(data)

Comment: then use `f = open("log.txt", "r")` instead of `f = data.split('\n')`. Rest will be the same. I used data to run it without your file which I don't have it. And this example everyone can copy and run without your file. it is common method to show working example.

Comment: If I have to remove TCP 0\.0\.0\.0 (.*) pattern from above code and find solution what code change is needed?

Comment: did you try to remove only `TCP 0\.0\.0\.0 (.*) ` from code ?

Comment: probably you would have to change numbers in `group()`  to `.group(1)` and `.group(2)`